# What is the Mandarin equivalent of Cantonese's 一係 A 一係 B?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

In Cantonese, you can use 一係 to present two options. For instance, you can say:

"Either eat or go" => 一係食一係走

In Mandarin, someone said 或者 is similar but lacks the same emphasis and force.

In other words, Mandarin speakers wouldn't say 或者吃或者走

So what's the Mandarin equivalent for 一係?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An equivalent expression is:
要麽 before each option

要麽吃，要麽走

Either eat or go.

要麽你去，要麽他去，我不能去。

Either you go or he goes; I can't.

Comment: Since 係 is the Cantonese counterpart of 是 in Mandarin, can we just replace 係 with 是 in this structure?  For example, [一係食一係走" --> "一是吃, 一是走"] ;[一係你去 一係佢去" --> "一是你去, 一是他去]

Comment: Mmm... never heard of "一是...一是..." in Mandarin. This expression seems to be southern - Cantonese "一係...一係...", some Min dialects/languages, such as Hokkien, Taiwanese, Longdu, use "一是...一是...". I am not familiar enough with other language families to know if it's used anywhere else. Perhaps others can chime in.

Comment: Which demonstrates that Cantonese isn't just Mandarin with a few interchangeable characters and funky tones...

Comment: 一是... 一是... is understandable I think, though it's not used often. I did hear the lines on TV, something like, 一个是生，一个是死， 你自己选择。The same concept here, 一个是吃，一个是走，which offers two options for people to choose from.

Comment: my mandarin friend said you can replace 一係 with 不要. so it would be like 不要吃，不要走

Comment: 不要吃，不要走 = Don't eat; don't go. Maybe your friend meant 要不吃，要不走？